# Javascript no reconoce HTML agregado con innerHTML desde AJAX con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, innerhtml

Estoy haciendo una petición AJAX a un PHP que me retorna un texto plano que no es más que un HTML que quiero luego agregar con Javascript mediante un innerHTML a un elemento del DOM, cuando lo hago uno de los elementos del HTML que he traído desde la petición es un botón, pero Javascript no lo reconoce como un elemento del DOM.

¿Como podría hacer que Javascript reconozca esos nuevos elementos(que son texto plano desde PHP) los cuales paso a un elemento como HTML con un innerHTML?

Sería algo así como:

(Respuesta petición desde PHP con echo):

```
<th >ID</th>
<th >Nombre</th>
<th >Estado</th>
<th ><input id="btn-borrar" type="button" name="delete" value="Borrar"/></th>
```

desde Javascript al responseText lo paso a una variable:

```
var x = response.responseText;
document.getElementById("DOMelem").innerHTML = x;
```

cuando termina de agregar y trato de clickear en el input, el Javascript no lo reconoce aún con el evento que tiene identificado Javascript del id de ese elemento, osea el addEventListener que le tengo a ese input desde el código.

Comment: En el código HTML que pusistes, no hay nada que tenga el ID "DOMelem", quizás sea por eso, agrega el ID "DOMelem" el elemento que quieras utilizar para insertarle contenido.

Comment: En el código original tengo el elemento seleccionado com btn-borrar, slo puse DOMelem de ejemplo, pero gracias por la observación @GermánMartínez

Answer (score 1):

lo que sucede es que es un elemento `dinamico` no existia al cargar la pagina puedes hacerlo de 2 formas 1:

```
<th ><input id="btn-borrar" type="button" name="delete" value="Borrar" onclick="acceralgo(this)"/></th>
//final del documento
<script>
    function acceralgo(e){
    //hago algo
    }
</script>
```

o la segunda forma es releyendo el documento con:

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e)){
 if(e.target.id == "btn-borrar"){
 ///code a ejecutar
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

El atributo outerHTML del interfaz DOM element obtiene el fragmento HTML serializado que describe el elemento incluyendo sus descendientes. Puede ser asignado para reemplazar el elemento por los nodos resultantes de examinar de la cadena proporcionada.

[outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

Comment: Podrías añadir un ejemplo en código para que el AP pueda ver claramente cómo esto soluciona su problema? Un saludo.